# How many shots would it take to sever a limb?

Tags: weapons, anatomy

Modern (or near future, 10-20 years) setting. Mostly regular humans. Regular firearms.

The scene goes like this: the Big Bad Villain of the story fought the Big Good Hero in hand-to-hand combat and won. He got his trusty gun, he stands above the defeated hero, he aims his gun at him... But he cannot pull the trigger. Because *deus ex machina* happens and a friendly character, that was imprisoned by the Villain and freed by the Hero on his way to final battle, comes to the rescue. This character, being a psychic capable of mind-controlling (like I said, *mostly* regular humans), overpowers weakened Villain and forces him to stop. Then, to repay the Villain for his "hospitality", the psychic forces the Villian to raise the gun and shoot off his own arm.

So here is the question (or rather two questions).

1) Is it even possible (with modern firearms) to shoot off person's limb with a single magazine/load of any one-handed non-automatic firearm? Preferably one without extended magazine.

2) What kind of calibre/ammunition type would be required for this?

**Edit**: What about explosive rounds? Are there any produced for handguns? Would they be better for this task?

Comment: _You_ need to define a calibre, I can think of weapons that will reportedly remove large parts of a human being when they miss by a narrow margin so how big is the gun and _then_ we can probably estimate how many rounds you need to take a limb off.

Comment: @Ash First I'd like to know if it's even possible period. Even if it is a monster revolver using .50 (which would probably break everything in users arm anyway) or sawed-off shotgun using 12 gauge.

Comment: Either one of those should do the job admirably, so would a solid slug from the sawn-off and a lot of smaller weapons with multiple rounds, you could use blanks from a .22 if the gun was barrel-to-flesh and get there eventually. Hell forget the gun, you could use a compressor at that range and do enough damage, eventually, to tear someones arm off.

Comment: @Ash Well, yes, 'eventually' an arm can be severed with pretty much everything. What I need is something reasonable that can 'cut' a limb in one load or magazine, because 17 shots from Glock won't be pleasant, but I doubt they will do the job. And I don't want my psychic to force the mind-controlled Villain with dozen of self-inflicted bullet wounds to reload his gun with one arm.

Comment: I'm not sure about explosive rounds since the force is dispersed in a sphere, therefore wasting a lot of punching potential. But you can always go the [FPS Russia way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbsgHbXubGU)... Plus, they are exotic rounds, it's not something you come across everyday and I don't think they are very useful for small calibres.

Comment: 17 shots from a Glock should be plenty, especially point blank. An arm near the shoulder has less than 17cms thickness (assuming *mostly* regular humans), so you'd be able to messily perforate it at less than every cm. Plus gas-damage from the muzzle blast - what makes you think there would be anything left to keep the 4-6kg of arm up?

Comment: Note that you could make the villain reload by holding the gun with his mouth and reloading with his free hand.

Comment: Sorry, but this query is off-topic for so many reasons! No worldbuilding involved; it's a real-world scenario; it's basically a plot or story question. Hence, am voting to close.

Comment: @elemtilas Do remember real world questions _can_ be on topic https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/is-a-real-world-question-off-topic. I personally think this one is, it asks a specific question about a specific scenario, it may be overly broad in it's lack of restrictions but it is on topic.

Comment: @Ash -- yes, "can" being the operative word. Which means that not all real-world questions are, or ought to be, on-topic. Even so, this is still a plot question! And the OP asks two questions, to boot!

Comment: @elemtilas Well, there is no Stack Exchange for guns or weapons. This one was the closest by theme I could think of. I doubt Biology or Physics would consider this on-topic.

Comment: @elemtilas I didn't say this was automatically on-topic, the way you stated it wasn't suggested that merely by being a real-world question it _could_ not be on-topic so I pointed out that this was not the case. I have stated my reasons for feeling that, in this case, the question should stand, although I'd rather it stood with only the second question and none of the others.

Comment: @MrScapegrace Question 2. is really enough for you to get the information you require, you might want to edit accordingly, as is the question rambles which is not doing you any favours on review.

Comment: @MrScapegrace -- Well, it's no more on-topic here than biology or physics! Basically: pick a number between 3 and 15; insert into plot; continue with story.

Comment: @MrScapegrace I'd say 1-15 and pick a big gun, but yeah elemtilas does have a point there.

Comment: @Ash, I'm not arguing with you. I was simply stating one of several reasons why I'd consider this question closeable. There are real-world questions that are appropriate here. This one (and so many many more I've seen recently), just no.

Comment: @elemtilas Fair enough, we see this question quite differently so we naturally differ greatly on whether it's on or off topic

Comment: I don't understand how this question is plot based. It does not ask anything about the story. It's only looking for a one handed firearm that could sever a limb, with a single magazine. For me, it a bit broad but still a viable question. In addition, it's a near-future question so you can still create fictional weapons and calibres. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean "off" as in falls on the floor right now and you want it done in one or possibly two shots your best bets are:

- a sawn-off shotgun firing, it probably doesn't matter at pointblank range, I'd say 12 gauge, buck and ball, or solid slug, those will get the job done.
- any .50 cal handgun that fires actual [.50 BMG rounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_BMG), purportedly those rounds will take a limb in a near miss.

A lot of lighter weapons will get the job done over the course of several well aimed shots, and some really light rounds could cause later loss of the limb from trauma with a single well aimed shot assuming the villain is in no state to seek immediate medical care. I would suggest that the villain staying conscious would be an issue for multiple shots so I'd go with something that will get the job done no questions asked.

Comment: Are there actual .50 BMG handguns? There are things like [.50 AE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_Action_Express) but I've never heard of pistols using .50 BMG.

Comment: @Hawker65 According to Wikipedia, Desert Eagle can use those. No idea if it's even possible to use them one-handed though.

Comment: @Mr Scapegrace Could you give me a link? The only .50 cal I see is .50 AE, which is way shorter than .50 BMG

Comment: @Hawker65 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMI_Desert_Eagle

Comment: @Hawker65 There's also these two https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Action_Thunder, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTS_.50.

Comment: @Mr Scapegrace As I said, this is only [.50 AE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_Action_Express), not [.50 BMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_BMG)

Comment: @Ash Nice, I was not sure .50 BMG pistols were a thing. Are there some with more than 1 shot?

Comment: @Hawker65 Not until you go up to carbine class weapons like the Barrett M82CQ which has a 10rnd mag as standard, which you can theoretically fire one-handed but you don't want to they're really heavy for carbines.

Comment: @Ash Plus, it probably isn't very handy to point at yourself to shoot your arm off. (I never thought I would say such a thing one day)

Comment: @MrScapegrace Saying .50cal doesn't mean the same thing all the time .50 BMG is either that, 50 Browning, or 12.7 x 99mm Nato anything else, including most .510 cal are lighter rounds.

Comment: @Hawker65 We all get that "I never thought I'd say that" feeling on this stack eventually, welcome to the club.

Comment: You couldn't have a .50BMG handgun - leaving aside recoil and weight issues for a moment, automatic handguns have the magazine in the handgrip. Given that a .50BMG round is 5.5" long, you wouldn't be able to hold it. A revolver would get around this problem, but you'd still need a foot or so of barrel plus a 6" receiver minimum.

Comment: @MattBowyer There are in point of fact two single shot bolt-action handguns that do pack a .50 BMG load, they're linked in an above comment, such handguns are not small, approximately 17 and 25 inches from memory, but they do exist.

Comment: Sort of proves my point - it's hardly a handgun, just a very short rifle with no butt-stock. I should perhaps clarify that you can't have a _practical_ .50bmg handgun.

Comment: @MattBowyer Practical is in the eye of the user and varies with circumstance, the smallest "carbine" that takes a round that big is over 45" which is certainly not a weapon you can conceal on your person, if you want one shot that you can hide and that _will_ settle the argument look no further. Yes personally I'd like something a little smaller with a larger ammo capacity but thankfully for all concerned I'm not a villain.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that 12 gauge would definitely remove all the meat , I'm not sure about severing the limb. If you target a joint, you probably have a better chance of severing a limb.

However, there are not any real one handed 12 gauge weapon. But what about sawn off shotguns? If you want to break your wrist and have the weapon fly off your hand, that is a safe bet but keep in mind that one shot might not be enough to sever a limb.

If you really don't care about that recoil factor, you could also use sawn off rifles (mare's leg style or a semi-auto). Since rifle rounds are much more powerful than pistol rounds, this could get the job done but over-penetration might be an issue (the round is so fast that it simply pierces and does not do major damage). However, since rounds from sawn off riffle tend to tumble a lot (because of the almost non-existent barrel length), this might compensate for this issue.

Otherwise, I would suggest high calibre handguns like a [S&W Model 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Wesson_Model_500) or a [Desert Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMI_Desert_Eagle). I'm pretty sure these would shatter a bone but you will need multiple shots to tear off the remaining flesh.

These are amongst the most powerful handguns so the recoil will be very strong here as well, so the previous remark about one handed shotguns remains valid here. You could go for less "overkill" handguns which use .44 Magnum for example.

I did not mention lower calibre pistols because I'm not sure of their ability to reliably break bone but I guess that, given the large magazine capacity of modern "low calibre" handguns (15 shots for the [M9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beretta_M9) or 20 for the [FN 5.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN_Five-seven)), you would have enough bullets to reliably sever an arm if you are accurate enough.

**EDIT** : When I'm talking about 12 gauge, the preferred ammunition would be buckshot. Never underestimate the power of buckshot.